# C++ undefined reference to 'WSAStartup@8' even though i linked ws2_32.lib

Tags: c++, codeblocks, winsock2

I use CodeBlocks, i've tried `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")` with and without giving a path, i tried adding it with linker settings, but it still shows the message, i even reinstalled CodeBlocks. Any ideas why i get the error? I might have made a small mistake since i'm still quite new to C++. Here's my code:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PORT 80

const char szHost[] = "";

using namespace std;

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    if(WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0){
        cout << "failure" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#pragma comment...` is MSVC specific.. Are you using g++? If so include the library in the project linker section.

Comment: i'm using MinGW

Comment: Did you try using #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32") ? i.e. without .lib extension? Also, I would suggest trying to include the ws2_32 without 'lib' in project settings. I have pasted your code to Visual C++ and it compiles fine. So this is definitely not a problem with the code itself, but with a misconfiguration of IDE/compiler.

Comment: `MinGW` is a project that provides the g++ compiler and toolchain.

Comment: then i'll try it

Comment: i tried them out, still no luck, i still have the same error as in the beginning

Comment: Where is the file "ws2_32.lib" on your computer? How does CodeBlocks know the exact path?

Comment: i have it in C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib i also gave codeblocks the path to it

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project` -> `Build options...`, then click on `Linker settings` tab.
Click on `Add` button and write `ws2_32`. 
[image]

Comment: already done this, doesn't work for me

Comment: It works for me. Could you post the complete content of the * .cbp file (CodeBlocks project file) of your program? It's the file that contains all the settings of the project.

Comment: I have also tried this, and it compiles fine until I add the line WSDATA wsadata; and then I get an error that WSDATA was not declared in this scope

Comment: You've added the header...#include <winsock2.h> ?